# "Being" more precisely

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, participles

> ***Being*** more precisely, I just don't even know what "end up" means.

I saw this sentece in a forum. Is use of "being" here correct? I would write it this way:

> ***To be*** more presicely, I just don't even know what "end up" means.

Comment: It looks like it should be 'precise' in both instances...

Comment: Hmm okay. What about use of "being" here? Is it a reduced clause?

Comment: As @Smock says: "Being more precise, ...", "To be more precise, ..." but also perfectly good: "More precisely, ..."

Answer (score 2):

The use of 'Being' is not incorrect here, but you can't use it with 'precisely' in this way.

It's either:

> Being more **precise**, I just don't even know what "end up" means.

or:

> More precisely, I just don't even know what "end up" means.

Both of these sentences should be preceeded by something is vague, that needs a more accurate statement to follow it up, to make it clear

Comment: Could yoy explain the use of "being" here? Is it a reduced clause?

Comment: I don't believe so - there's no 'who, which or that' here [that] I can see

Comment: By saying "reduced clause", I meant this kind of clauses :(https://www.grammarbank.com/reducing-adverbial-clauses.html)